# Intermittent Error on Windows Service: The underlying provider failed on Open

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, windows-services

I have a Windows Service running under the context of a Domain Service account that that communicates with a SQL Server database using. It runs every 10 minutes and communicates with the database each time.

I have had multiple occasions where it would run for a number a days then I found the service stopped because and exception was thrown.

Looking at the logs I find:

> Message: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> Stack Trace: at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() ...

with an inner exception of:

> Message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)
>
> Stack Trace:    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) ...

I checked with the DBA that manages the SQL Server and the server was up and running when the errors occurred and nothing relevant was in the logs to indicate downtime or loss of network connection.

The Windows Service is built with .NET 4.5 using Entity Framework 6. It uses the following connection string:

```
<add name="AmceContext" 
         connectionString="data source=ServerName\InstanceName;initial catalog=DbName;integrated security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I could just set the Windows Service to restart automatically if it stops. But I would like to find the underlying issue. I also thought of [Connection Resiliency](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/connection-resiliency-and-command-interception-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) but this could cause issues since this error could also occur when installing the service, if the server name wasn't right. In other words it could keep retrying a bad connection name.

I setup DebugDiag and ran an analysis against the dump file, it gave me the following recommendation:

> Please follow up with vendor Microsoft Corporation for problem
>   resolution concerning the following file:
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\ce681fb89786c8f11e99ae5f8e9588ab\mscorlib.ni.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a network issue. My best suggestion is you work with the network people at your organization and figure out if there may be some underlying intermittent networking problems.

A workaround that may or may not work in your case is try connecting to the IP and port of the DB server directly instead.

More information about troubleshooting this exact issue can be found on the following MSDN blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

Comment: What is odd is the message "Error Locating Server/Instance Specified" -- you would think it would be a timeout issue.